# Is the external micro SD card path the same for all devices?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, file-system, external-sd

I am using a Samsung Tab 2.

There is a path: `/mnt/external_sdcard/myfile`. Here, I can save, read, or write my file to the external micro SD card.

I'm just wondering if this path is the same for all devices, or if it may be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: No.

On my device (LG P990 Optimus 2X) the path changed after upgrading from 2.3 to 4.0. Currently the path on my device is `/mnt/sdcard/external_sd`.

So this is highly dependent on the device provider or on the version.

Comment: Same path here on my Cat tablets running JB (4.1.1). I'd almost say it might depend on the Android version (so 4.x is very likely to have this path), but as we saw so many different manufacturer-specific implementations in the past, I'm not sure if they now decided to agree on a common path...

Comment: Izzy you are getting this path /mnt/external_sdcard or what Uwe told that path.

Comment: MY old HTC Incredible S (running ICS) had it as /mnt/sdcard for the external (no internal) SD card.  My Galaxy S3 (updated to 4.1) has the external SD card at /mnt/extSdCard