# OS Update moved external_sd to extsdcard; Apps previously on SD card are now missing/uninstalled.

Tags: updates, external-sd, sd-card

I just upgraded my Galaxy Note (1st gen) from ICS 4.0.x to JS 4.1.2. I'm using the Samsung ROM supplied by my carrier (with all the bloat in it).
After the upgrade, I noticed many of my apps were missing (the ones installed on the SD card), as well as my photos/videos and personal files (previously stored in `sdcard/external_sd/DCIM/...`).

So I checked various parameters, and using a file explorer, I found out that all the `sdcard/` contents moved to `storage/sdcard0`, and the `sdcard/external_sd` moved to `storage/extSdCard`. I found my personal files, and my photos/videos, but the apps previously installed on the sdcard are no longer installed. Also, the gallery app doesn't detects the photos taken before the upgrade.

Can someone enlighten me about why my SD Card apps are missing/uninstalled?

Comment: That is not unusual and already answered [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39144/is-the-external-micro-sd-card-path-the-same-for-all-devices).

Comment: The link @UwePlonus provided only explains that mount points can and do change with OS upgrades. The overall question is still unanswered on why the change broke everything (the apps would still be installed in the new location).

Comment: @StephenSchrauger, yes, and I tried taking a picture with the default camera app (with picture location set to SD card), and it goes to `storage/extSdCard/DCIM`, so it understood the relocation...